# Prevent continue Typing in TextBox When a Char is Entered

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a textbox which user should type a price in it. 
I need to prevent continue typing if price starts with 0.
For example user can not type "000" or "00009".

I tried this on KeyPress, but nothing!

```
if (txt.Text.StartsWith("0"))
       return; Or e.Handeled = true;
```

Comment: Refusing to allow any typing when the price starts with 0 seems like a poor user experience - notably, they may want to type a backspace to *remove* the character if they entered it in error. A softer approach that highlights the text box and refuses to submit the entire form, whilst allowing edits/corrections would usually be preferred.

Comment: Yes User can backspace and delete, but if it starts with 0 it can not type another char.

Comment: Should it be `e.Handeled = true`? [Reference](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2591284/1050927), and you may need to check user input `numeric` instead of control character (backspace, delete...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
private void textBox1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    //only allow digit and (.) and backspace
    if ((e.KeyChar < '0' || e.KeyChar > '9') && e.KeyChar != '\b' && e.KeyChar != '.')
    {
        e.Handled = true;
    }

    var txt = sender as TextBox;

    //only allow one dot
    if (txt.Text.Contains('.') && e.KeyChar == (int)'.')
    {
        e.Handled = true;
    }

    //if 0, only allow 0.xxxx
    if (txt.Text.StartsWith("0")
        && !txt.Text.StartsWith("0.")
        && e.KeyChar != '\b'
        && e.KeyChar != (int)'.')
    {
        e.Handled = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: instead of `e.KeyChar != '\b'` it is better to use `!char.IsControl(e.KeyChar)`

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `TextChanged`-event for this.

```
private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (this.textBox1.Text == "0") this.textBox1.Text = "";
}
```

This will only work, if the `TextBox` is empty on startup.

Comment: I do not want to empty the text box after entering 0 at start. I just want to prevent continue typing in this situation.

Comment: You can still use text changed

Answer (score 0):

I solved it Myself:

```
private void txtPrice_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    if (txtPrice.Text.StartsWith("0") && !char.IsControl(e.KeyChar))
    {
        e.Handled = true;
        return;
    }
}
```