# showing password characters on some event for passwordbox

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, xaml, user-interface, passwords

I am developing a windows phone application.In that i ask the user to login.

On the login page the user has to enter password.

Now what I want is that i give user a check box which when selected should show the characters of the password.

I have not seen any property on password box to show password characters.

Please suggest some way to do it.

Comment: **Related post on how to achieve it in WinForms** - [How can I unmask password text box and mask it back to password?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8185747/465053)

Comment: **Related post for WPF** - [Where can I find a free masked TextBox in WPF?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/481059/465053)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Don't think that is possible with PasswordBox... just a thought, but you might accomplish the same result using a hidden TextBox and when the user clicks the CheckBox, you just hide the PasswordBox and show the TextBox; if he clicks again, you switch their Visibility state again, and so on...

**Edit**

And here it is how!

Just add a page, change the ContentPanel to a StackPanel and add this XAML code:

```
<PasswordBox x:Name="MyPasswordBox" Password="{Binding Text, Mode=TwoWay, ElementName=MyTextBox}"/>
<TextBox x:Name="MyTextBox" Text="{Binding Password, Mode=TwoWay, ElementName=MyPasswordBox}" Visibility="Collapsed" />
<CheckBox x:Name="ShowPasswordCharsCheckBox" Content="Show password" Checked="ShowPasswordCharsCheckBox_Checked" Unchecked="ShowPasswordCharsCheckBox_Unchecked" />
```

Next, on the page code, add the following:

```
private void ShowPasswordCharsCheckBox_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    MyPasswordBox.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Collapsed;
    MyTextBox.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;

    MyTextBox.Focus();
}

private void ShowPasswordCharsCheckBox_Unchecked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    MyPasswordBox.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;
    MyTextBox.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Collapsed;

    MyPasswordBox.Focus();
}
```

This works fine, but with a few more work, you can do this fully MVVM'ed!

Comment: Well, it doesn't work, because VS2015 says, you can't bind the password of a passwordbox :(

Comment: yep, not working anymore, maybe update your answer in that way.

Comment: And for full MVVM'iness, you should also use `Visibility="{Binding ShowPassword, Converter={StaticResource BoolToHiddenConverter}}"` or similar. Don't set the Visibility in code behind.

Answer (score 1):

with default passwordbox it's not possible to implement the feature you want.

more information you can find here: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/wpf/thread/98d0d4d4-1463-481f-b8b1-711119a6ba99

Comment: That post is quite old and right now does not reflect the true nature of PasswordBox.Password, because right now this is a Dependency Property so you can bind to it!

Answer (score 1):

You could create your own control that inherits from textbox however after each character you replace it with an *, storing the true value within a private variable on the page. Using a checkbox you can then toggle whether the value in the textbox shows the true value or the * value.

It's not an elegant solution nor is it a best practice, however I think it's still an alternative if you are willing to live with it.

Answer (score 1):

I created an MVVM example, which I'm also using in real life. Please note that PasswordBox.Password is not a Dependency Property and thus cannot be bound directly. It's designed like that for security reasons, for details see: [How to bind to a PasswordBox in MVVM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1483892/how-to-bind-to-a-passwordbox-in-mvvm#answer-1493330)

If you want to do it anyway, you have to build a bridge to your view model using code behind. I'm not providing the converters, as you're probably using your own set of converters. If not, please ask google for suitable implementations.

**EnterPasswordWindow.xaml**

```
<Window x:Class="MyDemoApp.Controls.EnterPasswordWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyDemoApp.Controls"
        mc:Ignorable="d" d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance local:EnterPasswordViewModel}"
        WindowStartupLocation="CenterOwner" ResizeMode="NoResize" SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight"
        Title="Enter Password">
    <StackPanel Margin="4">
        <TextBlock Margin="4">Please enter a password:</TextBlock>
        <TextBox Margin="4" Text="{Binding Password, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Visibility="{Binding ShowPassword, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisibleConverter}}"/>
        <PasswordBox Margin="4" Name="PasswordBox" Visibility="{Binding ShowPassword, Converter={StaticResource BoolToCollapsedConverter}}" PasswordChanged="PasswordBox_PasswordChanged"/>
        <CheckBox Margin="4" IsChecked="{Binding ShowPassword}">Show password</CheckBox>
        <DockPanel>
            <Button Margin="4" Width="150" Height="30" IsDefault="True" IsEnabled="{Binding Password, Converter={StaticResource StringIsNotNullOrEmptyConverter}}" Click="Button_Click">OK</Button>
            <Button Margin="4" Width="150" Height="30" IsCancel="True" HorizontalAlignment="Right">Cancel</Button>
        </DockPanel>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

**EnterPasswordWindow.xaml.cs**

```
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;

namespace MyDemoApp.Controls
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for EnterPasswordWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class EnterPasswordWindow : Window
    {
        public EnterPasswordWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            DataContext = ViewModel = new EnterPasswordViewModel();
            ViewModel.PropertyChanged += ViewModel_PropertyChanged;
        }

        public EnterPasswordViewModel ViewModel { get; set; }

        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            DialogResult = true;
            Close();
        }

        private void ViewModel_PropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (!mSuppressPropertyChangedEvent && e.PropertyName == nameof(ViewModel.Password))
            {
                PasswordBox.Password = ViewModel.Password;
            }
        }
        private bool mSuppressPropertyChangedEvent;
        private void PasswordBox_PasswordChanged(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            mSuppressPropertyChangedEvent = true;
            ViewModel.Password = ((PasswordBox)sender).Password;
            mSuppressPropertyChangedEvent = false;
        }
    }
}
```

**EnterPasswordViewModel.cs**

```
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;

namespace MyDemoApp.Controls
{
    public class EnterPasswordViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public string Password
        {
            get => mPassword;
            set
            {
                if (mPassword != value)
                {
                    mPassword = value;
                    NotifyPropertyChanged();
                }
            }
        }
        private string mPassword;

        public bool ShowPassword
        {
            get => mShowPassword;
            set
            {
                if (mShowPassword != value)
                {
                    mShowPassword = value;
                    NotifyPropertyChanged();
                }
            }
        }
        private bool mShowPassword;

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        private void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName]string propertyName = null)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(propertyName))
            {
                return;
            }
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```