# A good way to show password in PasswordBox

Tags: c#, passwordbox

I wonder i some one have any good idea how to show the password in the PasswordBox.
Have read that you can bind a textbox to a passwordbox but isnt it another way to do it.

Comment: I always use TextBox for this purposes. Try it

Comment: I still want to hide the value in the textbox

Comment: heh, as turned out its not trivial. look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10091466/showing-password-characters-on-some-event-for-passwordbox

Comment: **Related post** - [Where can I find a free masked TextBox in WPF?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/481059/465053)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want your password to be visible you should use a textbox. The only function of a password box is to mask input. It doesn't provide extra functionality. Its also possible to switch your textbox and password box at runtime

Comment: But if i have a textbox i want to be able to make it look like a passwordbox. So when i write in the textbox is dots instead of letters and then i have a button to show the actuall value

Comment: In that case. Try this.myTextBox.PasswordChar = '*'. Let's see how this works

Comment: "The only function of a password box is to mask input" - just wanted to point out that the WPF PasswordBox stores the value securely in memory in the SecurePassword property (which is a [SecureString](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.securestring(v=vs.110).aspx)), which a TextBox doesn't do.

Answer (score 0):

There are no any inbuilt properties to show password character in PasswordBox control. But we could do this by TextBox control to display Password in PasswordBox. For PasswordBox with show/hide functionality in WPF. We will use Two TextBlock controls, TextBox control, PasswordBox control, Image control

## XAML

```
<Grid>
    <TextBlock Text="Welcome&#xa;To see the Password"
               FontSize="28"
               FontWeight="Bold"
               HorizontalAlignment="Center"
               VerticalAlignment="Top"
               TextAlignment="Center"
               Margin="0,30,0,0" />
    <TextBlock Text="Enter your password"
               FontSize="20"
               HorizontalAlignment="Left"
               Margin="112,160,0,0"
               VerticalAlignment="Top" />
    <TextBox Height="40"
             FontSize="20"
             Padding="5,2,47,0"
             HorizontalAlignment="Left"
             Margin="112,193,0,0"
             Name="txtVisiblePasswordbox"
             VerticalAlignment="Top"
             Width="274" />
    <PasswordBox Height="40"
                 FontSize="20"
                 Padding="5,2,47,0" 
                 HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                 Margin="112,193,0,0"
                 Name="txtPasswordbox"
                 VerticalAlignment="Top"
                 Width="274"
                 PasswordChanged="txtPasswordbox_PasswordChanged" />
    <Image Visibility="Hidden"
           Height="30"
           HorizontalAlignment="Left"
           Name="ImgShowHide"
           Stretch="Fill"
           VerticalAlignment="Top"
           Width="30"
           Margin="351,198,0,0"
           MouseLeave="ImgShowHide_MouseLeave"
           PreviewMouseDown="ImgShowHide_PreviewMouseDown"
           PreviewMouseUp="ImgShowHide_PreviewMouseUp" />
</Grid>
```

## Code Behind

```
string AppPath = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    ImgShowHide.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(AppPath + "\\img\\clip.jpg"));
}
private void ImgShowHide_PreviewMouseUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    HidePassword();
}

private void ImgShowHide_PreviewMouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    ShowPassword();
}
private void ImgShowHide_MouseLeave(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    HidePassword();
}
private void txtPasswordbox_PasswordChanged(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if(txtPasswordbox.Password.Length > 0)
        ImgShowHide.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
    else
        ImgShowHide.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
}

void ShowPassword()
{
    ImgShowHide.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(AppPath + "\\img\\cus.jpg"));
    txtVisiblePasswordbox.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
    txtPasswordbox.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
    txtVisiblePasswordbox.Text = txtPasswordbox.Password;
}
void HidePassword()
{
    ImgShowHide.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(AppPath + "\\img\\clip.jpg"));
    txtVisiblePasswordbox.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
    txtPasswordbox.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
    txtPasswordbox.Focus();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

here's a good and easy way, u can just download the password font from [Here](https://www.onlinewebfonts.com/download/51b459eae74df5b00ba922028ccb20be)
and use it in the textbox as a font instead of passwordbox whenever you want to show a password all you have to do is just switch the fonts from "Password" to "Microsoft Sans Serif" or anything //
For example when I click the CheckBox :

```
Private Sub ChkShowPass_Click(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs)
    If ChkShowPass.IsChecked = True Then
        'show Password
        TxtPassword.FontFamily = New FontFamily("Microsoft Sans Serif")
    ElseIf ChkShowPass.IsChecked = False Then
        'hide Password
        TxtPassword.FontFamily = New FontFamily("Password")
    End If
End Sub
```

hope this will help you and help many programmers.