# How can i change the PasswordBox?

Tags: c#, vb.net

Please how can i change the asterisk of a passwordbox to char ( i will use a checkbox to show or hide the value of password) in c#
when the checkbox is cheked the password box change to be like a textbox with keeping the value inside

Comment: Is this web, winforms, or WPF, or... ?

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this you have to mask the password character.

Please refer this.

[how can i unmask c# password textbox and mask it back to password](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8185747/how-can-i-unmask-c-sharp-password-textbox-and-mask-it-back-to-password)

Answer (score 0):

## Introduction

It is not clear that what you want, or what are you making in, VB or C#. But for your comfort I have written in both, as far as I understood.

## Code And Example

### In C#

To assign `PasswordChar`:

```
TextBox2.PasswordChar = "*";
```

OR

```
TextBox2.PasswordChar = "☻";
```

To remove `PasswordChar`:

```
TextBox2.PasswordChar = "";
```

### In VB.net:

To assign `PasswordChar`:

```
TextBox2.PasswordChar = "*"
```

OR

```
TextBox2.PasswordChar = "☻"
```

To remove `PasswordChar`:

```
TextBox2.PasswordChar = ""
```

## Explanation

You can assign whatever password char you want to in double quotes ahead of `PasswordChar` property of `textbox`. To remove `PasswordChar` there should be no value in the double quotes about which we talked above.

I hope it's clear and works perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

Use a Textbox instead and change its property `yourTextBox.UseSystemPasswordChar` - set it to false if you wish to see the text. If you want to use a checkbox to control that, you can use something like:

```
Private Sub yourCheckbox_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles yourCheckbox.CheckedChanged

        If (yourCheckbox.Checked = true) then

            yourTextBox.UseSystemPasswordChar = true

        Else

            yourTextBox.UseSystemPasswordChar = false

        End If

 End Sub
```

This is VB.Net, but in case you are looking for C#, the corresponding code should be pretty easy to infer.