# Displaying and Hiding Password Char

Tags: c#

I am creating password enable/disable show option in my Windows Forms. I drew this up, and it is not working. Any reason why? There are not errors shown. The password fields are simply not changing when the button is clicked.

```
   if (textBox3.PasswordChar == '*')
    {
        textBox3.PasswordChar = '\0';
    }
    else if (textBox3.PasswordChar == '\0')
    {
        textBox3.PasswordChar = '*';
    }
```

Comment: insetead of `'\0'` use `""`, it should work,

Comment: "" - cannot convert string to char. I think you meant '' ?

Comment: Then change it to `''`

Comment: Yes, sorry, mistake :)

Comment: ' ' - Error: Empty character literal. I think \0 is the closest you can get to this without an error... Giving me an error there.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish by setting the `PasswordChar` to a null character?

Comment: For the actual password to show instead the **** or password chars at TextBox3.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how can i unmask c# password textbox and mask it back to password](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8185747/how-can-i-unmask-c-sharp-password-textbox-and-mask-it-back-to-password)

Answer (score 2):

Should be as simple as this.  The simple part is remove the other if statement.

```
        if (textBox3.PasswordChar == '*')
        {

            textBox3.PasswordChar = '\0';
        }
        else
        {
            textBox3.PasswordChar = '*';
        }
```

Comment: if you want to downvote then provide a reason as what I posted works.

Comment: Wasn't my downvote, but you could have at least stated what was so simple

Comment: Funny part. Still not fixed :(. I don't know who downvoted. Same goes for mine.

Comment: Then you have other issues and should post the full code. My guess is that you do not set the PasswordChar after the control intitalizes.

Comment: Oh. I deserve a walk of shame. Sorry for wasting everyone's time. I just saw passwordchar was not filled and UseSystemPasswordChar was on.

Comment: No worries @OracleStart, it happens to the best of us.