# How to change the contents of textbox to any one of the special characters using checkbox in c#?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

**Explanation:**

I have one checkbox named **hide password** and two textboxes named **password** and **conform password** respectively.Those two textboxes have been already binded with the **old password** as follows.

```
Password: Apple
Conform Password: Apple
```

Once I select the **hide password checkbox**,the old password which is already in the **password** textbox and **conform password** textbox, should change to ******** .

**For Example**:  If my **old password** is **Apple** as soon as I check the **hide password checkbox** it should change to ***** as follows.

```
Password: *****
Conform password: *****
```

Is it possible with c# (wpf) using MVVM?

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_toggle_password.asp

Comment: But I need c# code...@David784

Comment: @GJPD that's not [how this site works](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: I have edited my question up to my knowledge ....Someone help me..

Comment: Why not use `PasswordBox` that's what it's for. You can set and clear the mask and it stores the password in a secure string. [This may help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8185747/how-can-i-unmask-password-text-box-and-mask-it-back-to-password)

Comment: But, Is it possible to bind two properties to one password box?......I actually need it for this purpose https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54264195/is-it-posssible-to-bind-two-properties-to-single-textbox-using-mvvm-c @JSteward

Answer (score 1):

The following solution uses a `TextBox` to show the password in plain text and a `PasswordBox` to mask the password. The `PasswordBox` is on top of the `TextBox`, so at first you'd see the password masked. When the "show password" checkbox is checked, the `PasswordBox` is hidden, thereby showing the `TextBox` beneath (and the password in plain text). Here's the XAML:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="VisibilityConverter" />
</Window.Resources>

<StackPanel>
    <Grid>
        <TextBox
            Text="{Binding Password, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
            />
        <PasswordBox
            x:Name="PasswordBox"
            PasswordChanged="OnPasswordChanged"
            Visibility="{Binding HidePassword, Converter={StaticResource VisibilityConverter}}"
            />
    </Grid>
    <CheckBox
        Content="Show password"
        IsChecked="{Binding ShowPassword}"
        />
</StackPanel>
```

It doesn't use MVVM for everything (notice the `OnPasswordChanged` event handler). This is because the `PasswordBox` can't use binding, so the password must be set in the code-behind. But before showing that, here's the view model:

```
public class ViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    private string _password;
    public string Password
    {
        get => _password;
        set => Set(ref _password, value);
    }

    private bool _showPassword;
    public bool ShowPassword
    {
        get => _showPassword;
        set
        {
            Set(ref _showPassword, value);
            RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(HidePassword));
        }
    }

    public bool HidePassword => !ShowPassword;
}
```

The `Set` methods come from the `ViewModelBase` parent class, which is part of the MVVM Light Toolkit. The `Set` method simply sets the property's backing field and raises the `PropertyChanged` event for that property.

Finally, here's the code behind:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        InitializeViewModel();
    }

    public ViewModel ViewModel => DataContext as ViewModel;

    private void InitializeViewModel()
    {
        DataContext = new ViewModel();

        ViewModel.PropertyChanged += (sender, args) =>
        {
            // Update the password box only when it's not visible;
            // otherwise, the cursor goes to the beginning on each keystroke
            if (!PasswordBox.IsVisible)
            {
                if (args.PropertyName == nameof(ViewModel.Password))
                    PasswordBox.Password = ViewModel.Password;
            }
        };
    }

    private void OnPasswordChanged(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ViewModel.Password = PasswordBox.Password;
    }
}
```

After setting the `DataContext` to a new `ViewModel`, we listen to changes to the `Password` property so that we update it in the `PasswordBox`. Notice that we only do this when the `PasswordBox` is not visible (otherwise, the cursor is set to the beginning on each keystroke and we end up with the password reversed!)

The event handler simply updates the `Password` in the view model whenever it's changed in the `PasswordBox`.

The code for the "confirm password" `TextBox` and `PasswordBox` would be very similar.

Comment: you are requested to see the following post as well to understand my requirements completely https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54264195/is-it-posssible-to-bind-two-properties-to-single-textbox-using-mvvm-c  @redcurry

Comment: @GJPD Questions should be as self contained as possible. If your question needs to be expanded to fully explain your problem, please edit your question.

Comment: okay...is it possible to do what you said without adding anything in code behind? @redcurry

Comment: @GJPD Not if you're going to use the `PasswordBox`. It doesn't support data-binding for security reasons, so we're forced to use code behind.

Comment: k...Thank you for your Info?

Answer (score 0):

you could solve this by means of a Converter that checks whether you should hide or show the actual Text.
By the use of a MultiValueConverter we can pass in both the original text and a bool which specifies whether we should hide or show it. The return value then is either the actual text or the hidden text:

```
public class PasswordToHiddenCharactersConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (values.Length != 2)
        {
            return string.Empty;
        }

        var passwordText = (string)values[0];
        var hidePassword = (bool)values[1];

        if (hidePassword)
        {
            return string.Empty.PadRight(passwordText.Length, '*');
        }

        return passwordText;
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return new[] { value };
    }
}
```

This then can be used in the XAML to bind the text of the TextBox and it will display correctly depending on the value of the CheckBox:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <local:PasswordToHiddenCharactersConverter x:Key="PasswordToHiddenCharactersConverter" />
</Window.Resources>

<StackPanel>
    <CheckBox x:Name="HidePasswordBox" Content="Hide Password" />
    <TextBox >
        <TextBox.Text>
            <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource PasswordToHiddenCharactersConverter}" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged">
                <Binding Path="Password" />
                <Binding ElementName="HidePasswordBox" Path="IsChecked" />
            </MultiBinding>
        </TextBox.Text>
    </TextBox>
</StackPanel>
```

"Password" is the property name in our ViewModel, for the CheckBox we can directly bind it from within the xaml wihtout having to go via the ViewModel

Comment: If I type in a password, then hide it, and then type more of the password, the second part is shown while the first part is hidden.

Comment: @redcurry
You're right, this is due to the missing "UpdateSourceTrigger" in the Multibinding.
I updated the code snippet with this and that should solve that problem