# How to make password text box value visible when the cursor is over an icon in winform

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox

I am creating a `winforms` application using `C#`. Now I want to add a small eye `Icon` next to the password `textbox` so when the user hovers over the `Icon`, one can see what is entered so far. So while hovering, the `textbox` should show `123` and when the user leaves the icon the box should be shown as `***` again . Is there any way to do this with `C#`?

Comment: I don't think the database you're using is relevant. Added the winforms tag.

Comment: @DanGuzman *Added the winforms tag* And where is it? 

Comment: [TextBox with show password eye icon](https://github.com/r-aghaei/TextBoxWithShowPasswordEyeIcon)

Answer (score 5):

```
textBox.UseSystemPasswordChar = true;
icon.MouseEnter += (sender, e) => textBox.UseSystemPasswordChar = false;
icon.MouseLeave += (sender, e) => textBox.UseSystemPasswordChar = true;
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

On the hover event use :

Recommended - use an if condition to validate if hover called & set `UseSystemPasswordChar` property to `true` or `false` based on the action.

```
//hover condition
if() {   
   textBox1.UseSystemPasswordChar = False;
} else {
   textBox1.UseSystemPasswordChar = True;
}
```

Or

```
textBox1.PasswordChar = '\0';
```

**The UseSystemPasswordChar property has precedence over the PasswordChar property. Whenever the UseSystemPasswordChar is set to true, the default system password character is used and any character set by PasswordChar is ignored.** - [Source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.textbox.passwordchar?view=netframework-4.8#System_Windows_Forms_TextBox_PasswordChar)

More Solutions could be found at [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8185747/how-can-i-unmask-password-text-box-and-mask-it-back-to-password)

Official Documentation .Net Framework 4.8:

`UseSystemPasswordChar` - [This Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.textbox.usesystempasswordchar?view=netframework-4.8#System_Windows_Forms_TextBox_UseSystemPasswordChar)

`PasswordChar` - [This link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.textbox.passwordchar?view=netframework-4.8#System_Windows_Forms_TextBox_PasswordChar) (Not masked textbox)

`MaskedTextBox.PasswordChar` - [This link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.maskedtextbox.passwordchar?view=netframework-4.8#System_Windows_Forms_MaskedTextBox_PasswordChar)

Answer (score 0):

In hover event on icon, you need change `PasswordChar` property of TextBox to `char.MinValue`
like this:

```
textBox1.PasswordChar = char.MinValue;
```

And then if user leave icon, change this property again

```
textBox1.PasswordChar = '*';
```