# what is the most ideal approach to enter Time to Textbox in HH:MM organize in WPF?

Tags: wpf, time, textbox

I need to enter Time esteem in textbox. this is the configuration I need, HH:MM. what is the most ideal approach to enter Time to Textbox in HH:MM arrange? any example code for this?

Comment: http://wpftoolkit.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=MaskedTextBox

Comment: possible duplicate of [Where can I find a free masked TextBox in WPF?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/481059/where-can-i-find-a-free-masked-textbox-in-wpf)

Comment: Whether its winforms or WPF, I've always found masked textboxes to be a bit of a pain, and they can behave in unexpected ways. I would just let the user enter a value, then validate that it conforms to HHMM or HH:MM format (just personal preference though). A common approach is to have separate dropdowns for hours and minutes. Have a look at other UIs for inspiration, and see how they do it.

Comment: We can have DropDown for HH. but if we go for MM control, its some what difficult to scroll down and set value to 0-59.