# Implementing masked Textboxes

Tags: wpf

I am creating a `WPF` application and I am having difficulties implementing masked input onto text boxes.

For example:

> User enters **0830**, but it is automatically changed to **08:30**

Another example:

> Entering a contact number like **0895541026** is automatically changed to **(089) 554 1026**

If entering a currency value then to have a decimal point after the last 2 digits.

Is there a simple way to accomplish this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Where can I find a free masked TextBox in WPF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/481059/where-can-i-find-a-free-masked-textbox-in-wpf)

Comment: `having difficulties implementing masked input onto text boxes`, can you please show the code you are having issue's with so we can replicate and help you further?